# Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, in image caption model with LSTM and VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, training-data

I am training an image captioning dataset with 3 images and 5 captions for each, the model is working fine i printed every variable to check what it contains but when I reach model.fit() this error appears

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_23/2295231336.py in <module>
      8     generator=data_generator(train, mapping, features, tokenizer, max_length, vocab_size, batch_size)
      9     # fit for one epoch
---> 10     model.fit(generator, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1661                 if logs is None:
   1662                     raise ValueError(
-> 1663                         "Unexpected result of `train_function` "
   1664                         "(Empty logs). Please use "
   1665                         "`Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or "

ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

here is the layers and compile part

```
# encoder model
# image feature layers
inputs1 = Input(shape=(4096,))
fe1 = Dropout(0.4)(inputs1)
fe2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)
# sequence feature layers
inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
se1 = Embedding(vocab_size, 256, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
se2 = Dropout(0.4)(se1)
se3 = LSTM(256)(se2)

# decoder model
decoder1 = add([fe2, se3])
decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(decoder1)
# outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=["acc"],run_eagerly=True)

# plot the model
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

here is the training part

```
# train the model
epochs = 20
batch_size = 32
steps = len(train) // batch_size

for i in range(epochs):
    # create data generator
    generator=data_generator(train, mapping, features, tokenizer, max_length, vocab_size, batch_size)
    # fit for one epoch
    model.fit(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
```

here is what's inside train, it is the name of two pictures that used for training

```
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
['1000268201_693b08cb0e', '1001773457_577c3a7d70']
```

it is my first image captioning training model with my own data set, I used the same model before to work with Flicker and it works fine, can anyone please help me, Thank You